# Apple Lion upgrade failed horribly, Wiki won't start

Tags: mac-osx, apple, lion

So another admin here upgraded our OS X Snow Leopard Server to Lion Server and there have been failures across the board of services in general. One of the more serious issues is the failure for the Wiki service to start.

This is the first I've had to deal with an Apple server so I'm not completely positive how I can go about debugging this. I'm a Unix admin and have been looking all over the place for relative logs or some way to try to start the wiki service directly with debug flags, but I can't find anything.

Basically, using the Server admin panel to start the Wiki service shows it flipping from On back to Off, and using `serveradmin start wiki` returns it as "STARTING" status, and a subsequent check with `serveradmin fullstatus wiki` shows it as "STOPPED". I'm ready to pull my hair out!

Comment: something seems to fail while the wiki starts up. try to get more verbose output by issueing the startcommand (e.g. the command behind serveradmin start wiki) on the commandline and watch what happens.

Comment: how can I determine what the command behind the `serveradmin start wiki` is? I'm not at all accustomed to OS X services

Comment: `tail -f /var/log/system.log` and then try to start the service?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Library/Logs Permissions Looks like this is an issues all around with the upgrade.